# vue js watch на массив словарей

Tags: javascript, vue.js

С backend-а приходит массив словарей, и при изменении любого значения в словаре нужно получить либо значение ключа "id" словаря, либо индекс ячейки массива, для того что бы отправить на backend этот словарь. Но у меня не получается использовать watch с массивом, при попытке отслеживать изменения в массиве я получил ошибку - Watcher принимает только простые пути, разделенные точками. Вопрос возможно ли отслеживать изменения в ячейках массива с помощью watch, количество ячеек массиве может быть любое. Буду благодарен за любую помощь или совет.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Опция `deep: true`, переданная в вотчер, вас спасет. Подробнее в документации: [документация](https://ru.vuejs.org/v2/api/#vm-watch).

Comment: Хотя по ссылке можно найти ответ на вопрос, лучше указать здесь самое главное, а ссылку приводить в качестве источника.  Если страница, на которую ведет ссылка, будет изменена, ответ-ссылка может стать недействительным. — [из очереди проверок](/review/low-quality-posts/339722)

Comment: @Dmitriy, формально главное как раз здесь указано: нужная опция.

Comment: @Grundy Ну не знаю, тут вроде обычно подобного рода ответы просят дополнять хотя бы парой слов о том, как именно работает предложенное решение.

Comment: @Dmitriy, дополнить да, но формально, он был бы не ответом, если бы отсутствовало первое предложение, а была бы просто ссылка на документацию.

Comment: @Grundy А, ну ок.

Comment: Возможно ли при изменении массива получить индекс ячейки в которой изменилось значение?

Comment: Нет. В обработчик будет передано новое значение массива и старое. Можете вычислять разницу динамически.

Comment: То есть самому пробегать массив и искать что изменилось?

Comment: Да, именно так. Или пользуйтесь методом difference из lodash.

Comment: Спасибо за помощь .